# Best way to remove all "target" folders in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, intellij-15

How can I automate the removal of 'target' folders to facilitate a clean build process for my project in IntelliJ?

[image]

Comment: Build | Rebuild project will clean it automatically. What problem are you trying to solve that cannot be solved by Rebuild?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! When I hit Shift+F9 (or click "bug" icon) to start debugging, I found that IntelliJ does not clean content of the previous builds in "target" folders. So sometimes I have to go and delete those folders manually, so when I hit Shift+F9 next time, it produces a new / clean build.

Comment: This is the expected behavior of the incremental compiler (Build action). Target folder is removed only on Rebuild.

Comment: OK, thank you! Build | Rebuild should work in my case.. Could you please post your answer? - I'll mark it as a right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to clean the `target` directory and perform a clean build in IntelliJ IDEA, please use the Build | **Rebuild Project** action.